# Landscape fails when using openstack-installer (even /experimental fails)

Tags: openstack, canonical, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Here's the log:

```
[DEBUG • 02-11 00:48:30] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • (dialog.py, _build_widget, 93)]
   Num items: 2, items: <ListBox selectable box widget>
[DEBUG • 02-11 00:48:42] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • (dialog.py, submit, 111)]
   Callback on : OrderedDict([('password', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('confirm_password', <EditInput selectable flow widget>)])
[DEBUG • 02-11 00:48:45] • cloudinstall.ui • (__init__.py, submit, 214)]
   Callback on : OrderedDict([('Landscape OpenStack Autopilot', (<RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Landscape OpenStack Autopilot' state=True>, 'Benefit from best practices in cloud building, and get up and running within minutes, all from an intuitive web UI.')), ('Multi', (<RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Multi' state=False>, 'OpenStack installation utilizing MAAS.')), ('Single', (<RadioButton selectable flow widget 'Single' state=False>, 'Fully containerized OpenStack installation on a single machine.'))])
[INFO  • 02-11 00:48:45] • cloudinstall.install • (install.py, do_install, 129)]
   Performing a Landscape OpenStack Autopilot install
[DEBUG • 02-11 00:48:45] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • (dialog.py, _build_widget, 93)]
   Num items: 4, items: <ListBox selectable box widget>
[DEBUG • 02-11 00:51:32] • cloudinstall.ui.dialog • (dialog.py, submit, 111)]
   Callback on : OrderedDict([('admin_email', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('admin_name', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('maas_server', <EditInput selectable flow widget>), ('maas_apikey', <EditInput selectable flow widget>)])
[DEBUG • 02-11 00:51:32] • cloudinstall.landscape_install • (landscape_install.py, _save_lds_creds, 81)]
   Existing MAAS defined, doing a LDS installation with existing MAAS.
[DEBUG • 02-11 00:51:36] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, ssh_genkey, 817)]
   ssh keys exist for this user, they will be used instead.
[DEBUG • 02-11 00:51:36] • cloudinstall.multi_install • (multi_install.py, do_install, 137)]
   Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/root/.cloud-install/juju juju  bootstrap 
[DEBUG • 02-11 01:03:54] • cloudinstall.multi_install • (multi_install.py, do_install, 173)]
   Finished MAAS step, now deploying Landscape.
[ERROR • 02-11 01:53:33] • cloudinstall.multi_install • (multi_install.py, run_deployer, 756)]
   Problem deploying Landscape: {'output': "2015-02-11 01:04:04 [DEBUG] deployer.cli: Using runtime GoEnvironment on maas\n2015-02-11 01:04:05 [INFO] deployer.cli: Starting deployment of landscape-dense-maas\n2015-02-11 01:04:05 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Getting charms...\n2015-02-11 01:04:05 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /root/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_haproxy-1\n2015-02-11 01:04:05 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/haproxy-1\n2015-02-11 01:04:06 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /root/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_postgresql-3\n2015-02-11 01:04:06 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/postgresql-3\n2015-02-11 01:04:07 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /root/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_landscape-server\n2015-02-11 01:04:08 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/landscape-server-5\n2015-02-11 01:04:09 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /root/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_apache2-4\n2015-02-11 01:04:09 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/apache2-4\n2015-02-11 01:04:10 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /root/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_rabbitmq-server-7\n2015-02-11 01:04:10 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Retrieving store charm cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-7\n2015-02-11 01:04:11 [DEBUG] deployer.charm: Cache dir /root/.cloud-install/juju/.deployer-store-cache/cs_trusty_landscape-server\n2015-02-11 01:04:11 [DEBUG] deployer.deploy: Resolving configuration\n2015-02-11 01:04:11 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connecting to environment...\n2015-02-11 01:04:12 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connected to environment\n2015-02-11 01:04:12 [INFO] deployer.import: Deploying services...\n2015-02-11 01:04:12 [DEBUG] deployer.import: <deployer.env.go.GoEnvironment object at 0x7f953c0d6ed0>\n2015-02-11 01:04:13 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service apache2 using cs:trusty/apache2-4\n2015-02-11 01:04:13 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Refetching status for placement deploys\n2015-02-11 01:04:24 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service haproxy using cs:trusty/haproxy-1\n2015-02-11 01:04:30 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service landscape using cs:trusty/landscape-server\n2015-02-11 01:04:37 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service landscape-msg using cs:trusty/landscape-server\n2015-02-11 01:04:41 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service postgresql using cs:trusty/postgresql-3\n2015-02-11 01:04:47 [INFO] deployer.import:  Deploying service rabbitmq-server using cs:trusty/rabbitmq-server-7\n2015-02-11 01:04:58 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Adding units...\n2015-02-11 01:04:59 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service 'apache2' does not need any more units added.\n2015-02-11 01:04:59 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service 'haproxy' does not need any more units added.\n2015-02-11 01:04:59 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service 'landscape' does not need any more units added.\n2015-02-11 01:04:59 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service 'landscape-msg' does not need any more units added.\n2015-02-11 01:04:59 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service 'postgresql' does not need any more units added.\n2015-02-11 01:04:59 [DEBUG] deployer.import:  Service 'rabbitmq-server' does not need any more units added.\n2015-02-11 01:04:59 [DEBUG] deployer.import: Waiting for units before adding relations\n2015-02-11 01:08:27 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/0 change:pending\n2015-02-11 01:08:42 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/1 change:pending\n2015-02-11 01:08:52 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/2 change:pending\n2015-02-11 01:09:02 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/3 change:pending\n2015-02-11 01:09:17 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/4 change:pending\n2015-02-11 01:09:27 [DEBUG] deployer.env:  Delta machine: 0/lxc/5 change:pending\n2015-02-11 01:53:32 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connecting to environment...\n2015-02-11 01:53:33 [DEBUG] deployer.env: Connected to environment\n2015-02-11 01:53:33 [ERROR] deployer.import: Reached deployment timeout.. exiting\n2015-02-11 01:53:33 [INFO] deployer.cli: Deployment stopped. run time: 2968.46\n", 'status': 1}
[DEBUG • 02-11 01:53:33] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, global_exchandler, 62)]
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/utils.py", line 77, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/machinewait.py", line 127, in do_continue
    self.installer.do_install()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 177, in do_install
    self.loop).run()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 706, in run
    self.deploy_landscape()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 721, in deploy_landscape
    self.run_deployer()
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/multi_install.py", line 757, in run_deployer
    raise Exception("Error deploying Landscape.")
Exception: Error deploying Landscape.

[INFO  • 02-11 03:19:36] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, cleanup, 90)]
   Cleanup, saving latest config object.
[DEBUG • 02-11 03:19:36] • cloudinstall.utils • (utils.py, cleanup, 96)]
   Attempting to reset the terminal
```

We are setting up an Ubuntu cloud PoC, and are in the process of going with a 100 node license.

Comment: It was taking too long to install landscape (50min?), so it gave up. What kind of hardware are you using? Do you have a particularly slow network or disk?

Comment: Also you are running the installer as the 'root' user. You should be running it with `sudo` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It was a BIOS issue.

I have 4 NICs in each node and only two were connected. The timeout for the installer kicked in while the NICs kept trying to PXE boot.